# Locally revert commit from cloned repository/reset all changes after specific commit

Tags: git, gitlab, git-checkout, git-revert

I have cloned repository and went to branch `developer` (`git checkout developer`). I would like to locally revert commits (to commit with SHA: `2403d2547f9183531bbd81672d887186bba34579`) which someone made, pushed and merged to branch `developer`. I don't want to change anything on repository, just locally on my machine. How can I revert this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do `git revert`, or whatever else you want to do, and don't push the changes.

By default, whatever you do in a git repository is done locally, and you need to use the `push` command to push the changes. So just do the change, and don't do a `git push`.

If you want to revert a specific commit, and preserve everything else, you can use `git revert commit_sha`.

But in this case, it also looks like what you may really want is "revert" a specific commit and all the commits after it. In this case, if you don't want to push it (for example, you just want to compile the specific version of the code, or do some debugging of that specific version) you may want to use `git reset --hard commit_sha^` which will "go back" to state from before the `commit_sha`, or `git reset --hard commit_sha` to go back to the state at the exact `commit_sha` with this commit still included.

Comment: but how will it knows to which version I would like to revert? Is there a chance to revert to commit with SHA `2403d2547f9183531bbd81672d887186bba34579`?

Comment: `git revert commit-sha` should work. In your case, `git revert 2403d2547f9183531bbd81672d887186bba34579`.. Note that it will create a revert commit, not delete the existing commit.

Comment: Nope, I tried:
`git revert 2403d2547f9183531bbd81672d887186bba34579` and got 
`fatal: bad object 2403d2547f9183531bbd81672d887186bba34579`

Comment: This means commit with this sha doesn't exist in your clone of the repository. Make sure you are in the correct branch, and you can see commit history with `git log` and copy sha from there.

Comment: so to sum up:
there were 3 commits after the commit with SHA `2403d2547f9183531bbd81672d887186bba34579` and after `git revert 2403d2547f9183531bbd81672d887186bba34579` I won't see these commits which were made after this one with SHA `2403d2547f9183531bbd81672d887186bba34579`?

Comment: git revert will try to only revert the one specific commit. If there are any conflicts resulting from that, you may need to resolve these conflicts. It looks like in this case, what you really want is `git reset` which allows you to "go back" to the state of specified commit. IU will update the answer with information how to do that.

Comment: Yes, sorry if I wasn't clear enough ;/
I would like to reset all changes which were made after this specific commit. I would like to have everything what happend to that commit (included).